# .net core 3.1 Google SSO Callback url not hit

Tags: identityserver4, google-signin, .net-core-3.1

I followed a link to achieve google SSO [github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1370](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1370). But even after successful login it is taking me to redirect uri mentioned in authentication property. It is not taking to the callback url. Could someone help on this? Our application is a `.net core 3.1` with `IdentityServer4.`
Am expecting `signinoauth2 API` to be hit after google login, but thats not happening.

I could see a network call from browser with below format and getting correlation error.
https://localhost:44368/signinoauth2?state=***&code=***&scope=***&prompt=none

> Exception: Correlation failed.
>   Show raw exception details
>   Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   Soulbook.Api.Startup+<>c+<b__5_1>d.MoveNext() in Startup.cs
>   await next.Invoke();
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   PFB my code for reference,

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [Route("/Feed")]
        public ActionResult Feed() 
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/signin")]
        public ActionResult SignIn()
        {
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/"
            };
            return new ChallengeResult(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, authProperties);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/signinoauth2")]
        public ActionResult<LoginResponse> signinoauth2Async([FromForm]object data)
        {

            return Ok();
        }

Startup.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;


services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                      .AddCookie(o => {
                          o.LoginPath = "/signin";
                          o.LogoutPath = "/signout";
                          o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                      })
                      .AddGoogle(o => {
                          o.ClientId = "***";
                          o.ClientSecret = "**";
                          o.SaveTokens = true;
                          o.CallbackPath = "/signinoauth2";
                      });

services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                                .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddNewtonsoftJson();



EDIT: Having signinoauth2 in any one of the below formats also doesnt help.
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/signinoauth2")]
        public ActionResult<LoginResponse> signinoauth2Async(string state, string code, string scope, string prompt)
        {

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/signinoauth2")]
        public ActionResult<LoginResponse> signinoauth2Async(string state, string code, string scope, string prompt)
        {

            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to get Google user information in your enpoint?
Then what you have to do is configure the external authentication properties. And thanks to this you are going to be able to get the user on your redirect endpoint.

```
    [HttpGet("login/google/")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginGoogle()
    {
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "/api/identity/google-redirect");
        return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

What you configured on startup is a callback route which gets handled by Middleware and never hits the endpoint in your controller. What you want to achive is get user on redirect route like this

```
    [HttpGet("google-redirect")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CallbackGoogle()
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't actually being properly authenticated, if you were the app would redirect to the landing page whose controller I assume has an [Authorize] attribute. Could you have possibly forgotten to add yourself as a user in the db that your identity server is referencing?

Comment: When can we add this google user to our identity server? i hope on hitting callback url..but its not gettting hit. Thats my actual problem. Am adding my code also in my question for better clarity.

Comment: try hitting ctrl+f5 and also just f5 on the page to try to clear your cookies, or try in an incognito window and see if that acts differently. (try this a bunch of times to see if it is a cookie caching issue)

Comment: does your sign in page have some kind of ajax call to the oauth2 post route in your /signinoauth2 route containing controller?